# How do I make exponential graph show only one trend-line with two lists of data?

Tags: plotting, functions, physics, dataset

Below is my code containing two lists of data, I need the graph to show one exponential trendline from an exponential equation, but it currently shows one trendline per item in the list. I am sure this is an easy fix, but I am new to mathematica so I am struggling a bit. There is also an image of the output.

```
Current := Is * (Exp[(V/Vt)] - 1)
Is = {0.055015, 0.00598, 0.0706, 0.0356, 0.1231, 0.158, 0.04873, 
  0.0928, 0.0642, 0.07535}
Vt = 0.045
V = {0.759, 0.660, 0.768, 0.735, 0.790, 0.797, 0.750, 0.780, 0.760, 
  0.767}
Plot[Current, {V, -1, 1.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you seek:

```
is = {0.055015, 0.00598, 0.0706, 0.0356, 0.1231, 0.158, 0.04873, 0.0928, 0.0642, 0.07535};
vt = 0.045;
v = {0.759, 0.660, 0.768, 0.735, 0.790, 0.797, 0.750, 0.780, 0.760, 0.767};

ClearAll[current]
current[v_] := is*(Exp[(v/vt)] - 1)
ListPlot@Transpose@{v, current[v]}
```

[image]

As an aside, I recommend avoiding single uppercase letters as variable names, as well as uppercase names in general, since those may conflict with built-in function names.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: @Molly You are very welcome!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get a best fit equation from that graph?

Comment: @Molly To what model would you like to fit it? What would be the parameters? you may want to look into [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html).